# How to return a class member string in groovy script

Tags: groovy

I have the following code snipet

```
class **ResultToken** {
 String token
 String expiration
}


// HTTP post request to retrive active token
// Return : ResultToken object
ResultToken getToken(){
ResultToken token

http.request(POST) {

    ...

    response.success = { resp, json ->
    token = new ResultToken(token: json["access_token"].toString(), 
expiration: json["expires_in"].toString())

    }
}    
token
}

def tokenValue =getToken().token
return tokenValue
```

**Exception error :**
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: http for class: Script259
    at Script259.getToken(Script259.groovy:21)
    at Script259.run(Script259.groovy:41)

Any idea?

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you define the handler which doesn't return anything usefull.

It should rather be:

```
ResultToken getToken(){
  ResultToken token

  http.request(POST) {
    ....
    response.success = { resp, json ->
      token = new ResultToken(token: json.access_token, expiration: json.expires_in)
    }
  }

  token
}
```

Comment: I have try your suggestion but does not work, i get a missing property exception because I cannot access json.access_token. if as a return I use return json["access_token"], then I get the correct value but if I pass it through the ReultToken class it does not work. I have updated my initial post see the NOTE information

Comment: then use `json["access_token"]` instead of `json.access_token` inside the constructor.

Comment: I try but by doing so it says it cannot parse object to string because json["..."] seems not be return as string

Comment: add `toString()` to it, also you can deactivate `@CompileStatic`

Comment: ok synatch error gets removed with toString() added, but then when i try to return tk.token I get a wierd excpetion : groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: http for class: Script244
 at Script244.getToken(Script244.groovy:21)
 at Script244.run(Script244.groovy:41)

Comment: you must initialize your builder prior to calling it like `def http = new HttpBuilder( 'some.url' )`

Comment: sorry I did not put all declaration and initialisation to make it shorter but it is initialized

Comment: the exception inclines, that `http` is not even defined in your script

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works now . I gets a case sensitive issue :-(